# How do I Override styling from listview using c# wpf Visual studio 2013?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I'm making one of my first programs using wpf/c#/Visual Studio, and I'd like to remove/Override the style from this listview. So, the blue highlight, and also the effect on the headers.

[image]

Comment: Well this is the first time I've used this program, and I haven't used xaml before. So what I have tried is a lot of stuff I've found in google searches. I was able to change the color of the glow, albeit awkwardly, but never get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you have tried I can only provide a few links (which you should have been able to find by yourself).

- [ListView Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788747%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [WPF ListView Styling Tutorial Part I](http://blog.vascooliveira.com/wpf-listview-styling-tutorial-part-i/) and [WPF ListView Styling Tutorial Part II](http://blog.vascooliveira.com/wpf-listview-styling-tutorial-part-ii/)
- [Customizing ListView in WPF](http://ligao101.wordpress.com/2007/07/27/customizing-listview-in-wpf-part-i/)

Comment: This is much more helpful, then what I was able to find in google. I greatly Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In the designer you can right click on the controller then choose "Edit Template" -> "Edit Copy". This will create a copied template from the orignal then you can just edit it as you want and use the new style.